# How to detect that parameter is a tuple of two arbitrary types?

Tags: swift, types, casting, type-conversion, tuples

What I am actually doing is more complex but it comes down to being able to implement function to detect that something is a tuple, regardless of what the are the types of its elements.

This is my approch that does not work (see comment on last line) :

```
func isTuple(b: Any) -> Bool {
    return b is (Any, Any)
}

let myString = "aa"
let myDouble = 1.2
isTuple((myString, myDouble)) //returns false
```

Why doesn't it work? Shouln't `Any` act as a "wildcard" in tuples as well? Is it a known Swift bug (if not should I consider it one and report)? Is there other way how to make `isTupple` method work?

---

### EDIT

[@NateCook's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27133723/311865) fully answers original question but does it does not help me to do what I am trying to do. This is it:

I need not only to determine that something is a tupple but also to break it into its 2 values without knowing the exact type of those values.

Here is code:

```
func processIfTuple(b: Any) {
    if reflect(b).disposition == MirrorDisposition.Tuple {
        let (first, second) = b as (Any, Any) //error when casting
        process(first)
        process(second)
    }
}

func process(value: Any) {
    ...
}

processIfTuple(("aa", 1.2))
```

This does not work from similar reason that the test `b is (Any, Any)` does not work. This time there is error when trying to cast. Can this be solved? If not should it be considered language bug or missing feature and reported? It definitely leads to a LOT of code duplication because I need to test for all possible pairs of types for a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Swift's baby introspection methods to get at this:

```
func isTuple(b: Any) -> Bool {
    return reflect(b).disposition == MirrorDisposition.Tuple
}
```

Note that `reflect` is largely undocumented and may only be there as support for the playground / debugger, but as far as I know this is the only way to do this.

---

To achieve this you need to drill down into what `reflect()` gives you, which is a struct that conforms to `MirrorType`, which I call a reflection, for lack of a better term. You can subscript the reflection of a tuple to get reflections of the tuples members, and then get the value back out as `Any`. At that point you can use optional binding to safely rediscover the underlying type:

```
func process(value: Any) {
    println("Any \(value)")
}

func process(value: String) {
    println("String \(value)")
}

func processTuple(b: Any) -> Bool {
    let isTuple = reflect(b).disposition == MirrorDisposition.Tuple

    let r = reflect(b)
    for i in 0..<r.count {
        println(r[i].0)         // string holding tuple part name: ".0", ".1", etc
        println(r[i].1.value)   // the value of that tuple part: "aa", 1.2

        process(r[i].1.value)   // calls process(Any)
        if let val = r[i].1.value as? String {
            process(val)        // calls process(String)
        }
    }

    return isTuple
}

let myString = "aa"
let myDouble = 1.2
processTuple((myString, myDouble)) //returns false
```

Output:

```
.0
aa
Any aa
String aa
.1
1.2
Any 1.2
```

Comment: WAW, Nate, this is one of the best answers I ever got and my question here is one of the hardest. It clearly shows you have a significant expertise on the matter. I am going to set up a bounty on this question when available and reward you some extra reputation because it is worth it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, it's now done this way:

```
func isTuple(value: Any) -> Bool {
    if let type = Mirror(reflecting: value).displayStyle, type == .tuple {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

isTuple(value: ()) // true
isTuple(value: (1, 2) // true
isTuple(value: 3) // false
```