# Swift Pattern match on Array<Any>

Tags: swift, switch-statement, pattern-matching, swift1-2

Swift 1.2
I'm trying to pattern match in a switch case in a function that take a type Any as it's parameter, in order to dispatch to a private more specialize init.

Here is a Playground extrapolation :

```
import Foundation

struct myStruct {
}

func switchOnAny(any: Any) -> String {
    println("Dynamic Type == \(any.dynamicType)")
    switch any {
    case let array as [Any]:
        return "Array"
    case let array as NSArray:
        return "NSArray"
    default:
        return "Default"
    }
}

let emptyStringArray : [String] = []
let stringArray : [String] = ["Bob", "Roger"]
let intArray = [1, 2, 3]
let customStructArray : [myStruct] = []

println("\t\touput : \(switchOnAny([]))")
println("\t\touput : \(switchOnAny(emptyStringArray))")
println("\t\touput : \(switchOnAny(stringArray))")
println("\t\touput : \(switchOnAny(intArray))")
println("\t\touput : \(switchOnAny(customStructArray))")
```

Wich produce the following output :

> Dynamic Type == __NSArrayI
>           ouput : NSArray
>   Dynamic Type == Swift.Array
>           ouput : NSArray
>   Dynamic Type == Swift.Array
>           ouput : NSArray
>   Dynamic Type == Swift.Array
>           ouput : NSArray
>   Dynamic Type == Swift.Array<__lldb_expr_37.myStruct>
>           ouput : Default

I am wondering why the case `as [Any]` don't gets it since I'm never requesting an NSArray?

And can I assume that any kind of Swift array will get in the NSArray case or will I need to write 2 case statement (one for NSArray and one for [Any]) in order to cover my back (apparently there will be a need)?

---

After making some more test, I can see that when I'm providing an array of a custom struct none of the pattern will match. I will need to have a match like [myStruct] for it to recognize. Which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, because it is only one of the option that I can receive.

---

To give more context I've put my project on Github : https://github.com/VinceBurn/SwiftyPlist/tree/test/init-Any.
The project is about TDD and representing a Property list as a Struct like tree that can be accessed by subscript. (like SwiftyJSON)

Comment: Do you only want to filter values that are arrays (either `NSArray` or Swift `Array`)?

Comment: the input I want can be : Int, Float, String, myStruct, [Int], [myStruct], [String], [Float], [NSNumber], NSDate, NSData, [NSDate], [NSData], NSArray, NSDictionary, [String : myStruct]. So my goal would be to be able to have a single 'case' for all form of Array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift check if value is of type array (of any type)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033993/swift-check-if-value-is-of-type-array-of-any-type)

Comment: @VinceBurn I updated my answer with a pattern matching example.

Comment: Your linked example code is incorrectly using `Any`. You don't mean `Any`. You mean "types that can be converted to a property list." The fact that you needed a default assertion demonstrates that `Any` was the wrong tool. You want a `PropertyListConvertible` protocol. Then most of your complexity would go away. Rethink your problem in terms of protocols rather than in terms of type-casting and reflection.

Comment: @RobNapier I know that Any is a very imperfect solution, but using `case let array as [PlistConvertible]:` with extension on every type that can be converted to declare the protocol, still don't enter in the correct case when I'm passing an empty array of type [Plist]

Comment: Even though I said there is no workaround I've probably found a solution for your problem. See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately casting between generic types like `Array` is not fully supported (yet). There are also odd situations even if you want to upcast:

```
let emptyStringArray : [String] = []
emptyStringArray as [Any]    // succeeds

let stringArray : [String] = ["Bob", "Roger"]
stringArray as [Any]         // error! due to the elements?!

let intArray = [1, 2, 3]
intArray as [Any]            // error

let customStructArray : [myStruct] = []
customStructArray as [Any]   // '[myStruct]' is not convertible to '[Any]'
```

There is also no good workaround without using a protocol. If you really want to have this dynamic behavior you could use reflections with the `reflect()` function. In Swift 2 they are more powerful, but it is still not a good solution.

**Edit:**

A solution with a protocol which gets adopted by all `Arrays` through an extension (only for your specific case):

```
protocol ArrayType {
    var anyValues: [Any] { get }
}

extension Array: ArrayType {
    var anyValues: [Any] {
        return self.map { $0 as Any }
    }
}

// now the switch gets rewritten as
switch any {
case let array as ArrayType:
    let anyArray = array.anyValues
    return "Array"
case let array as NSArray:
    return "NSArray"
default:
    return "Default"
}
```

Comment: The last three examples of yours kinda do make sense, because e.g an array of `String`s doesn't occupy the same space as an array of `Any`: `sizeof(Any) = 32`, `sizeof(String) = 24`. To convert an array of a certain type to an array of `Any` you have to make an explicit cast (as mentioned they do not occupy the same space and don't represent the same): `stringArray.map{ $0 as Any }`. This may look weird and like it shouldn't be but it actually makes sense if you think about it.

Comment: @Kametrixom Great explanation. But the `map` could/should be done implicitly if you upcast. Hopefully in Swift 2.1

Comment: the thing with `as` is that it's not supposed to do nothing other than what the programmer wants. `as` only changes the representation of a variable and shouldn't change the underlying data. That's the reason this won't happen in the next Swift is that `as` should stay a non-cost operation, the programmer should do the more expensive cast when necessary himself. That's also the reason you can't cast directly with `as` from an `Int` to a `Double` and you have to use `Double(myInt)`.

Comment: @Kametrixom Even if it is changing the underlying data a cast from `String` to `Any` still succeeds but a generic type doesn't work? However optionals are a special case, they can be casted form `Optional<Int>` to `Optional<Any>`. Just curious, where did you get your information?

Comment: Ohh right it does work from String to Any.. Dunno why. I read it online, don't know where anymore, but there have been a lot of discussions about heterogenous collections recently, where I have seen the `.map{ $0 as Any }` and the explanation

Answer (score 3):

To decide the most reliably whether a variable is any kind of array is to use reflection, in **Swift 1.2:**

```
let array = []
let mirror = reflect(array)
let isArray = mirror.disposition == MirrorDisposition.IndexContainer
```

and in **Swift 2.0:**

```
let anArray = []
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: anArray)
let isArray = mirror.displayStyle == .Collection
```

And just for curiosity, it is interesting to check out these enums:

```
enum MirrorDisposition { //Swift 1.2
    case Struct
    case Class
    case Enum
    case Tuple
    case Aggregate
    case IndexContainer
    case KeyContainer
    case MembershipContainer
    case Container
    case Optional
    case ObjCObject
}

enum DisplayStyle { //Swift 2.0
    case Struct
    case Class
    case Enum
    case Tuple
    case Optional
    case Collection
    case Dictionary
    case Set
}
```

**UPDATED**
Here is a full pattern match example:

```
func switchOnAny(any: Any) -> String {
    println("Dynamic Type == \(any.dynamicType)")
    switch any {
    case let array as Any where reflect(any).disposition == MirrorDisposition.IndexContainer:
        return "Any kind of array"
    default:
        return "Default"
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution, however this does only a check wether the value is an array or not. It doesn't cast it to one.

Comment: @Qbyte as the OP said "...So my goal would be to be able to have a single 'case' for all form of Array", and it is accomplishes it.

Comment: Interesting, but the array is not cast to an Array, it is just cast to Any, so I can't use it as an Array, and when I try to cast it to something useful I have a case where I'm crashing.

Comment: @VinceBurn can you tell me which type causes the crash?

Comment: when I'm trying to cast the [myStruct] array

Answer (score 1):

I suggest extending the `Array` type with a custom protocol that you can use to check it like so:

```
protocol ArrayType {}
extension Array : ArrayType {}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
let array : Any = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array is ArrayType    // true
```

Also have a look at my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033993/swift-check-if-value-is-of-type-array-of-any-type/32034448#32034448).

But it actually looks like you don't want to have a single public initializer which takes `Any` as an argument (You very rarely want that at all), but rather two different initializers, one for arrays, one for non-arrays like so:

```
class MyClass {
    init<T>(array: [T]) {

    }

    init<T>(nonArray: T) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the protocol solution don't work for all case, I still have a case where it's passing over. And I actually want a single Init, because I want to implement the RawRepresentable. I will edit the question for more context.

Comment: @VinceBurn When it is passing over? In which case?

Comment: on this case : switchOnAny([]), when passing a non-casted Array. OK I need to add also : extension NSArray : ArrayType {}. But then how can I iterate over that collection in the switch case?

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion : in Swift 1.2

with the Kametrixom and Daniel Nagy answer, it is possible to enter a single switch case for all sort of Array.
But inside the case, I've not been able to cast the item to a usable array for all case.

So in conclusion I'm left with 2 case statement, one

```
case let array as NSArray:
    return "NSArray"
case let array as [myStruct]:
    return "myStruct array"
```