# Determine if Any.Type is Optional

Tags: swift, dynamic

I’m trying to determine if a given type `t` (`Any.Type`) is an optional type, I’m using this test

```
t is Optional<Any>.Type
```

but it returns always false.

So is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming that what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
let anyType: Any.Type = Optional<String>.self
anyType is Optional<Any>.Type // false
```

Sadly swift currently (as of Swift 2) does not support [covariance nor contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) and type checks directly against `Optional.Type` cannot be done:

```
// Argument for generic parameter 'Wrapped' could not be inferred
anyType is Optional.Type // Causes error
```

An alternative is to make `Optional` extend an specific protocol, and check for that type:

```
protocol OptionalProtocol {}

extension Optional : OptionalProtocol {}

let anyType: Any.Type = Optional<String>.self
anyType is OptionalProtocol.Type // true
```

Comment: The `OptionalProtocol` can have some nice uses: It can be used to provide [a *generic-less* interface to access the Optional values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989094/how-to-unwrap-an-optional-value-from-any-type/32780793#32780793) and [even the wrapped type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645612/check-if-variable-is-an-optional-and-what-type-it-wraps/32781143#32781143).

Comment: Very clever! It works perfectly in Swift 5.2 `let x = <someValue>; if type(of: x) is OptionalProtocol.Type { ... } `

Comment: Nice answer. Do you know how to get non-optional type from optional?

Comment: Yep, [this answer shows how to get the wrapped type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645612/check-if-variable-is-an-optional-and-what-type-it-wraps/32781143#32781143)

Answer (score 13):

A bit late for the party.  But, I ran into the same problem.  Here is my code.

```
func isOptional(_ instance: Any) -> Bool {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: instance)
    let style = mirror.displayStyle
    return style == .optional
}

let a: Int = 1 // false
let b: Int? = 2 // true
let c: Double = 3.0 // false
let d: Double? = 4.0 // true
let e: NSString = "Hello" // false
let f: NSString? = "Hello" // true


isOptional(a) // fasle
isOptional(b) // true - warning
isOptional(c) // false
isOptional(d) // true - warning
isOptional(e) // false
isOptional(f) // true - warning
```

It looks good to me. `swift4`

Answer (score 3):

Optionals conform to [`ExpressibleByNilLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebynilliteral), so you may use that:

```
let t = Optional<String>.self
t is ExpressibleByNilLiteral.Type // true
```

Comment: It's important to note that Apple says "Only the Optional type conforms to ExpressibleByNilLiteral. ExpressibleByNilLiteral conformance for types that use nil for other purposes is discouraged.". Otherwise, this would only be a necessary but not a sufficient condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
extension Mirror {
    static func isOptional(any: Any) -> Bool {
        guard let style = Mirror(reflecting: any).displayStyle,
            style == .optional else { return false }
        return true
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
XCTAssertTrue(Mirror.isOptional(any: Optional(1)))
```

Or if you need to cast from Any to Optional

```
protocol _Optional {
    var isNil: Bool { get }
}

extension Optional: _Optional {
    var isNil: Bool { return self == nil }
}

func isNil (_ input: Any) -> Bool {
    return (input as? _Optional)?.isNil ?? false
}
```

Usage:

```
isNil(nil as String?) // true
isNil("") // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```swift
public func isOptionalType(_ type: Any.Type) -> Bool {
  type is ExpressibleByNilLiteral.Type
  // or
  // String(describing: type).hasPrefix("Optional<")
}
```

```
(lldb) po isOptionalType(Int.self)
false

(lldb) po isOptionalType(Int?.self)
true
```

Answer (score -4):

You could use generics to achieve this:

```
func isOptional<T>(x:T?)->Bool
{
    return true
}

func isOptional<T>(x:T)->Bool
{
    return false
}
```

*Edit*

The code above can be used to know if a variable is of optional type. 
The only way i've figured out to know about a variable *containing* a type is by using reflection:

```
var t1:Any.Type=(String?).self
var t2:Any.Type=(String).self
Mirror(reflecting: t1).description
Mirror(reflecting: t2).description
```

The first call to Mirror gives the string `"Mirror for Optional<String>.Type"`, and the second gives `"Mirror for String.Type"`.

I understand that comparing string is not a convenient way to do this check, i will try again to find something more performant..

Comment: `t` is never an optional, it’s always a type object (probably representing an optional) so always the second method would be called.