# Swift - is there a way to determine if a variable is of tuple type in runtime?

Tags: swift, tuples

Is there a way to determine if a variable is of tuple type in runtime?

Comment: How is this variable declared?

Comment: Duplicate question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132761/how-to-detect-that-parameter-is-a-tuple-of-two-arbitrary-types

The accepted answer there is what you're looking for.

Comment: yep, confirmed! the accepted answer in the post linked above still works in Swift 2